# use placeholder value as value of input

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have a form where a user can edit a product on their website. it works fine if the user edits all fields, but if they don't, then it still sends the update query to the db, but replaces the fields they didn't fill in as empty. I have placeholders set on each input field so they can see which product they are editing and what they have in those fields already, so I was wondering what's the best way to basically do, if the value of the input field is empty, then set the value to whatever the placeholder is?

my code so far looks like this:

```
<form method="GET" action="/submitEdit" style="border: 2px solid black">

<input type="hidden" id="ogItem" name="ogItem" value="<%= itemName %>" style="border: 1px solid black" >


<fieldset>
        <legend><a href="/index"><span class="number">?</a></span>Enter The Following Details</legend>
    <label for="productName">Product Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="item" name="item" placeholder="<%= itemName %>" style="border: 1px solid black" >
    
    <label for="productPrice">Price:</label>
    <input type="text" id="price" name="price" placeholder="<%= itemPrice %>" style="border: 1px solid black">

    <!-- <label for="productCategory">Category:</label>
    <input type="text" id="category" name="category" placeholder="Socks" style="border: 1px solid black"equired> -->
      
      <label for="productCategory">SIZES (OPTIONAL):</label>
      <input type="text" id="size" name="size" placeholder="<%= itemSize %>" style="border: 1px solid black">

       <!-- submit image -->

    <button id="upload_widget" class="cloudinary-button">Upload Product Image</button>

    <script src="https://widget.cloudinary.com/v2.0/global/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

    <script type="text/javascript">  
    var myWidget = cloudinary.createUploadWidget({
      cloudName: 'xxx', 
      uploadPreset: 'xxx'}, (error, result) => { 
        if (!error && result && result.event === "success") { 
          console.log('Done! Here is the image info: ', result.info); 
          console.log(result.info.secure_url)
          var result_url = result.info.secure_url;
          console.log("result url is " + result_url)
          document.getElementById("url").value = result_url;
        }
      }
    )

    document.getElementById("upload_widget").addEventListener("click", function(){
      myWidget.open();

      }, false);
    </script>

    <!-- submit image end -->
    <input type="hidden" name="url" id="url" value="">

  </fieldset>
  <script>
    var itemid = document.getElementById('item')
    var itemid2 = document.getElementById('price')
    var itemid2 = document.getElementById('description')
    submitButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      if (itemid.value == ""){
        document.write('<input type="hidden" id="item" name="item" value="<%= itemName %>" style="border: 1px solid black" >')
      } else {
      alert("product added successfully \n ")
      }
    })
  </script>

  <fieldset>
    <label for="bio">Description:</label>
    <textarea id="bio" name="description" placeholder="<%= itemDesc %>" style="border: 1px solid black" ></textarea>
  </fieldset>
<button id="submitButton" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

I was thinking to use javascript to say something like, if (itemid.value == "") { set value of placeholder to the value of input}, but not sure if this is possible. Is this the best way to go about is since I need to check each input field and basically check which are empty and set the values to the placeholders? thanks in advance.

Comment: i think in get api from where you are getting data, you need to send the field value. and set this field value as value to your input. So user will see the pre-fill input values. whether they change it or not, you have to verify this in your backend.

Comment: "but not sure if this is possible" I don't see any reason it wouldn't work. You should try it! The other thing you can do is set a *pattern* on your inputs, which will stop the form from being submitted until the user has filled them out